Kubectl specify memory for horizontal pod
I’ve seen documentation  that kubectl can specify flags such as the target average CPU utilization:
kubectl autoscale deployment <deployment> --cpu-percent=50 --min=1 --max=10 

Why is there no flag for memory?

It is something that has been discussed and might be implemented in future. See this ticket for a full explanation:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/1481
